# Custom drawn view not drawn

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am currently trying to draw a star in a custom view. The class is IBDesignable and I can see the star in the interface builder. But when I compile and launch the app, the star is not drawn even though "drawRect" is called. Here is my code :

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    let starLayer = drawStarBezier(self.center.x, y: self.center.y, radius: self.frame.width/4, sides: 5, pointyness: 2)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    innerColor.setFill()
    starLayer.fill()
    UIColor.greenColor().setStroke()
    starLayer.stroke()
}
```

Here is what's shown in the interface builder :
[image]

And in the simulator :

[image]

Can anyone help me ?